# Using Coinbase Seed Phrase On MetaMask

Tags: metamask, wallets, coinbase

Is it safe to use the 12 word seed phrase from Coinbase Wallet...for MetaMask? I heard its not safe. When I tried it...it showed my coinbase balance. For MetaMask do you only need to use a MetaMask created wallet for existing user? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same phrase and run two wallets simultaneously. Checkout this article to know [why](https://medium.com/beam-mw/mimblewimble-multiple-devices-know-f65a8a12dd87#:%7E:text=DO%20NOT%20SIMULTANEOUSLY%20RUN%20TWO,please%20keep%20reading%20for%20details.)

If you found this answer useful, don't forget to upvote and mark it as correct for anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: The linked article appears to be specific to the Beam wallet, not necessarily the Coinbase wallet or Metamask.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to use the 12 word seed phrase from Coinbase Wallet...for MetaMask?

I'm pretty sure CB is a Metamask skin.

> I heard its not safe.

You are exposing your private key more than necessary

> When I tried it...it showed my coinbase balance.

goto answer[0]

> For MetaMask do you only need to use a MetaMask created wallet for existing user?

You can create as many as you want

> Thank you.

no problem